# How to use iosMath in SWIFT project? Resp. how to add MTMathUILabel() to project?

Tags: ios, swift, math, formulas

I am new to programming, but I am interested in how to use `iosMath` for iOS. I could instal Cocoa Pod already and I did import `iosMath` to project. Question is: how to visualise math equations?
I understand that it should be used `MTMathUILabel` for that, however I do not know, how to add it to program. Is there a way how to create subclass of `UIView` or something, to be able able to do it?

Here sample of my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore
import CoreText
import iosMath

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: MTMathUILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"
        label.sizeToFit()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I tried to connect label to `UIView()` and `UILabel()` in my Storyboard, but obviously thats not how it works.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems in your posted code

1. You are setting an `IBOutlet` then instantiating another `MTMathUILabel` with the same name
2. You don't really need to call `label.sizeToFit()`

Simple solution is to remove the `IBOutlet`, and do as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"

        //ADD THIS LABE TO THE VIEW HEIRARCHY
        view.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Better solution is as follows:

1. Create a `UIView` in storyboard (because `MTMathUILabel` is actually a `UIView`)
2. Set this view's class to `MTMathUILabel`
3. Connect the `IBOutlet` for this view

then use the following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: MTMathUILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //NO NEED TO INSTANTIATE A NEW INSTANCE HERE
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"
        //NO NEED TO CALL sizeToFit()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. This really helped and solved my problem. Thousands thanks :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Could you please accept this answer since your problem is now solved?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice that button to accept the answer at first. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: @Malik I get 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fb018e3dba0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.' this error whenever I try this... What should I do? I checked and the view is only connected to the right outlet... and it's weird because if I remove the connection it works but if I reconnect it, it doesn't, so I don't really know what I did wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: @Marybnq The error certainly points to an outlet being accessed before it is set. Ensure that the right outlet is connected in the storyboard. Also, make sure that the outlet is not accessed before `viewDidLoad` is called