# How to use iosMath math library in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, latex, nsview

I am interested in being able to type ***LaTeX*** to get *formatted Math Output* in my **macOS projects**. I have tried using the famous [iosMath](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iosMath) CocoaPod Library and also seen its working from their official examples [Repository](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) on GitHub. I am using Xcode 10, Swift 4.2 on macOS Mojave (10.14). Using the guidance given on the reply of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521273/how-to-use-iosmath-in-swift-project-resp-how-to-add-mtmathuilabel-to-project) I was able to successfully incorporate the library and make it render [Mathematical Text](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md) using latex in any iOS projects successfully. But it is giving great conflicts and problems in macOS. *After Installing the CocoaPod in my own project successfully* I tried to follow the *paradigm* given in their official [macOS Example](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/tree/master/MacOSMathExample) with several trials and errors but all resulting in failure.
I am describing whatever I tried as following:

- As we can see, the example projects have used XIBs instead of Storyboards but when trying out the ***same code and mechanisms on iOS in Storyboards it works just fine***.
- As per guidance in their example projects I have tried Using a Custom View both on iOS and macOS (i.e. UIView and NSView respectively) and attached that custom view to the custom class **MTMathUILabel** in the *Identity Inspector* in *Storyboard* And then of course linked it to an *IBOutlet* of type MTMathUILabel in my code file. It works successfully in the case of iOS but fails in macOS Even When I use *MTMathUIView* Custom Class in the Identity Inspector of Storyboard.
- In accordance to their [macOS example File](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/master/MacOSMathExample/AppDelegate.m) I typed *similar code* in my ViewController.Swift as given below:

`var mathViewCode: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
    @IBOutlet weak var mathViewIB: MTMathUILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mathViewIB.latex = "\\lim_{x\\to\\infty}\\left(1 + \\frac{k}{x}\\right)^x = e^k"
        mathViewCode.latex = "\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty} \\! e^{-x^2} dx = \\sqrt{\\pi}"

        self.view.addSubview(mathViewCode)
    }`

- When from the *above code* I execute only the *programmatically* called MTMathUILabel Variable Code then simply a blank window opens without any output in it. But when I try to use the IBOutlet Variable to print latex in the ***Custom NSView*** (whose Custom Class in Attributes Inspector has been set to MTMathUIView *not* MTMathUILabel because then it crashes) the app again opens with a ***blank window*** but this time with the following warning:

> Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property
>   on (NSWindow): -[NSView setLatex:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x60000330d7c0

- If in Storyboard's Identity Inspector for the Custom NSView I set the Custom Class to ***MTMathUIView*** then the Interface Builder *Does not Crash* but it doesn't work either and if I set it to ***MTMathUILabel*** then the Interface Builder ***Crashes*** with the following error:

> IB Designables: Failed to render instance of MTMathUILabel: The agent
>   threw an exception.

- However, in the above scenario (where the Storyboard's Custom NSView's Custom Class in Attributes Inspector has been set to MTMathUILabel) the app compiles successfully but throws the following run time error after crashing:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

As you can see, I have tried to follow the approaches given in their official [macOS Sample Project](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/tree/master/MacOSMath.xcodeproj) but nothing works in my case even though their ***Sample Project successfully compiles and runs*** well in my Xcode.

Please help me with this ***iosMath Library*** because I *really want to use it* because of its [Beautiful Output](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md) and *great features* or please suggest some other Math Library to type in ***LaTeX*** in my Mac Apps that *really runs on macOS with Swift*.
*Huge Thanks* In Advance!!

Comment: The `mathViewCode` label is invisible because its height and width are zero. Use `init(frame:)` or set `frame`.

Comment: Thank you; but on setting the frame it crashes again with the old runtime error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. 
I don't have a solution, but it is possible to use iosMath with MacOs and
 swift.
I created my Project LatexPic and added it to the original podfile. Now you can use it in macOS App in view controller like:

```
let latexlabel = MTMathUILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    self.view.addSubview(latexlabel)
    latexlabel.backgroundColor = .white
    latexlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    latexlabel.latex = "\\frac{2}{3}"

    }
```

Podfile:

```
workspace 'iosMath.xcworkspace'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'iosMathExample' do
  project 'iosMath.xcodeproj'
  pod 'iosMath', :path => './'
end

target 'iosMathTests' do
  project 'iosMath.xcodeproj'
  pod 'iosMath', :path => './'
end

target 'MacOSMath' do
  project 'MacOSMath.xcodeproj'
  pod 'iosMath', :path => './'
end

target 'LatexPic' do
    use_frameworks!
    project 'LatexPic.xcodeproj'
    pod 'iosMath', :path => './'
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness and help by offering such a humble and gentle solution!!