# Drawing labels using iosMath library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use iosMath but it shows nothing. How can I use the iosMath library to draw math labels?

> https://github.com/kostub/iosMath
>
> `iosMath` is a library for displaying beautifully rendered math equations in iOS and MacOS applications. It typesets formulae written using the LaTeX in a `UILabel` equivalent class. It uses the same typesetting rules as LaTeX and so the equations are rendered exactly as LaTeX would render them.

I installed pod file.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore
import CoreText
import iosMath


class Deneme_VC: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"

        //ADD THIS LABE TO THE VIEW HEIRARCHY
        view.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bli1H.png)

Comment: Unclear what the question is. You are showing us a screen shot of the code and the storyboard, but that's irrelevant. You won't see anything unless you actually _run_ the app.

Comment: I don’t know this library but if you are a beginner shouldn’t you learn the basics first like taking a tutorial on how to work with basic UIKit components.

Comment: Dear matt, when i run it, i see only white screen. i get the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521273/how-to-use-iosmath-in-swift-project-resp-how-to-add-mtmathuilabel-to-project/50522628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is somewhere in that library's docs, but...

You need to either give the `label` an explicit frame, or call `sizeToFit()`:

```
import UIKit

import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore
import CoreText
import iosMath

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"
        
        //ADD THIS LABE TO THE VIEW HEIRARCHY
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        // need to call sizeToFit() to get it to calculate the frame
        label.sizeToFit()
        
        // center it in the view
        label.center = view.center

        // so we can see the frame
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can I use this to put formulas in labels created in Storyboard that have outlets?  I tried this: `@IBOutlet weak var label: MTMathUILabel!` with `label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"` but it crashes with `Thread 1: "-[UILabel setLatex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12a005680"`

Comment: @Greg - did you set the class of the label in Storyboard to `MTMathUILabel`? It works fine for me.

Comment: that was it!  Thank you again!

Comment: @DonMag perfect explanation! 'Label.sizeToFit()' did the magic. Thanks man