# Trouble Installing iosMath

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am having trouble getting iosMath to work.

**Can anyone tell me what I may have missed?**  Here is what I have done:

I followed the instructions on
https://cocoapods.org/pods/iosMath (having never used cocoapods until now, there is much left out for us newcomers!).

First I had an issue just installing the podfile but finally got that done with the following (I got pages of error messages until I used Rosetta - I maybe because I have an M1 processor?):

- Close Terminal
- in Applications, right-click on Terminal, select "Get Info", then click "Open using Rosetta":

[image]

- close the window
- reopen Terminal
- enter: `sudo gem uninstall ffi`
- enter: `sudo gem install ffi`

Finally installing the podfile was successful:

- In Terminal, enter: `pod install`

This is the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.1'
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'iosMath', '~> 0.9'      
end
```

At this point, I expected this example (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63639192/8635708) to work:

```
import UIKit

import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore
import CoreText
import iosMath

class iosMathTest: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
    label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"

    //ADD THIS LABE TO THE VIEW HEIRARCHY
    view.addSubview(label)

    // need to call sizeToFit() to get it to calculate the frame
    label.sizeToFit()

    // center it in the view
    label.center = view.center

    // so we can see the frame
    label.backgroundColor = .yellow

}
```

However, on the `import iosMath` line, I get the error message: `No such module 'iosMath'`.  I've tried opening both MyApp.xcworkspace and MyApp.xcodeproj but both give me the same error.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: you may need to add `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile

Comment: Build the project to prime the Xcode module cache

Comment: @Paul Beusterien - I am pretty new - not sure I understand what that means...  I deleted the Derived Data folder and ran `Clean Build Folder`.

Comment: @Kiril S. - that did the trick! But I now see in the Frameworks folder that `libiosMath` and `Pods_MyApp.framework` are red.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it if your build works.